# Grouping content of an array into multiple nested arrays

Tags: arrays, swift

Here's a sample with a tiny amount of entries of my array of dates:

```
let dates: [Date] = [
Date.new(year: 1998, month: 04, day: 13),
Date.new(year: 1998, month: 04, day: 13),
Date.new(year: 1998, month: 04, day: 13),
Date.new(year: 1998, month: 04, day: 18),
Date.new(year: 1998, month: 04, day: 18),
Date.new(year: 1998, month: 04, day: 18),
Date.new(year: 1998, month: 07, day: 09),
Date.new(year: 1998, month: 07, day: 09),
Date.new(year: 1999, month: 07, day: 29),
Date.new(year: 1999, month: 07, day: 29),
Date.new(year: 1999, month: 09, day: 17),
Date.new(year: 1999, month: 09, day: 17),
Date.new(year: 1999, month: 09, day: 25),
Date.new(year: 1999, month: 09, day: 25)
]
```

By the way, I got the dates initialized using the following extension:

```
extension Date {
    static func new(year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) -> Date {
        return Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month, day: day))!
    }
}
```

Note that everything should be handled by code, because this array is filled by the user, and I do not normally know the dates in it, nor any year.

I am trying to create a sorted array of the dates, in a way that all the dates that are in the same day get an array, then, all arrays in same months are grouped together, then all arrays of same year are grouped together, then all arrays of years are grouped in a single big array.

I could give the following example:

```
[
[ [[13/2/1998 @ t1, 13/2/1998 @ t5], [25/2/1998 @ t565]], [[13/6/1998 @ t56]]] //Array for 1998
]
```

Anyway, I've created the following code, and it works. But the problem is it's getting messy, unreadable and unsustainable really fast, and I still have to group the dates by day and by "AM/PM".

```
extension Array where Element == Date {
func sortedByDates() -> [[[Date]]] {

    var years = [Int]()
    var monthsForYear = [Int : [Int]]()
    var sortedData = [[[Date]]]()

    for date in self {
        if !years.contains(date.year()) {
            years.append(date.year())
        }
    }
    print("years: \(years)")

    for year in years {
        for date in self {
            if date.year() == year {

                if monthsForYear[year] == nil {
                    monthsForYear[year] = [date.month()]
                } else if !(monthsForYear[year]?.contains(date.month()))! {
                    monthsForYear[year]?.append(date.month())
                }

            }
        }
    }
    print("months for each year: \(monthsForYear)")

    for (year, monthsOfYear) in monthsForYear {
        var contentForYear = [[Date]]()
        for month in monthsOfYear {
            var contentForMonth = [Date]()
            for date in self {
                if date.year() == year && date.month() == month {
                    contentForMonth.append(date)
                }
            }
            contentForYear.append(contentForMonth)
        }
        sortedData.append(contentForYear)
    }

    return sortedData
}
}
```

Comment: And? What have you tried? What results have you gotten?

Comment: @DuncanC I've updated it with what I've done.

Comment: Are you aware that grouping an array into a dictionary is a one-liner? For example, to group your sample array into a dictionary with a `1998` key and a `1999` key, each with the corresponding subarray as its value, is one line of code.

Comment: @matt Yeah, but I'm still creating the value subarray. How could I do it directly with 1 line?

Comment: The one-liner does that, that's my point.

Comment: @matt Can you please post an exemple as an answer so that I could understand how you do it?

Comment: Can _you_ please post a definition of your `dates` array that _compiles_? The whole problem is that this `Date.new` thing seems to be something you've made up, plus your `time` values are undeclared variables. So you have not provided a reproducible example. If you had done that, I would have written you the line of code long before now.

Comment: @matt I’ve just added to the question the extension needed to create these dates, nevermind the time for now, i’ve removed it

Comment: So to group those `dates` by year you would say `let d = Dictionary.init(grouping: dates, by: {Calendar(identifier: .gregorian).dateComponents([.year], from: $0).year!})`

Comment: However it seems to me this would all be much more efficient if you had an array of DateComponents instead of Date. Otherwise you keep combining the date components into a Date and then pulling it apart again to sort / combine it, which seems a little nutty.

Comment: @matt thanks alot, it works perfectly. I know, it’s nutty, but the problem is that the array in my app doesn’t contain dates, it contains objects that have a date property each.

Comment: That's not a problem at all. You just modify the closure accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show that you can group an array into a dictionary with subarray values in a single line. Just as an example to get you going, here's how you'd group your `dates` into individual years:

```
let greg = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let d = Dictionary(grouping: dates, by: {greg.dateComponents([.year], from: $0).year!})
```

If you wanted to, you could then transform that dictionary into some other form, such as an array of custom structs or pairs or whatever.